# Move branch pointer to different commit without checkout

Tags: git, git-branch

To move the branch pointer of a checked out branch, one can use the `git reset --hard` command. But how to move the branch pointer of a not-checked out branch to point at a different commit (keeping all other stuff like tracked remote branch)?

Comment: Sounds like all you wanted to do is a branch from a different commit than the one it is created from now. If my understanding is correct, then why don't you simply create a new branch from the commit you want to create it from using `git branch <branch-name> <SHA-1-of-the-commit>` and dump the old branch?

Comment: @yasouser - I am not sure whatever dumping "master" branch is a good idea.

Answer (score 635, accepted):

You can do it for arbitrary refs. This is how to move a branch pointer:

```
git update-ref -m "reset: Reset <branch> to <new commit>" refs/heads/<branch> <commit>
```

where `-m` adds a message to the reflog for the branch.

The general form is

```
git update-ref -m "reset: Reset <branch> to <new commit>" <ref> <commit>
```

You can pick nits about the reflog message if you like - I believe the `branch -f` one is different from the `reset --hard` one, and this isn't exactly either of them.

Comment: Seeing as It's been 6 months and Jefromi hasn't turned his/her comment into an answer, I'm doing it as community wiki so it gets exposure.  I personally didn't see it until I had done a branch -f!

Comment: Where is the message good for? Where is it stored and how to read it later?

Comment: @PhoneixS thanks for the edit. @MikeL - probably shows up in the reflog? (try `git reflog` to see it)

Comment: *NOTE:* This does not work on bare repositories.  On bare repositories, you have to use 'git branch -f master <commit>' to update the branch (see the answer below).

Comment: Strange, this did what I wanted it to do, but did not appear in the reflog.

Comment: If, like me, you accidentally use <branch> instead of refs/heads/<branch>, you'll end up with a new file in your .git directory at .git/<branch>, and you'll get messages like "refname 'master' is ambiguous" when you try to work with it. You can delete the file from your .git directory to fix.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "arbitrary refs"? Chris Johnsen's answer below branches from an arbitrary commit if I am not mistaken.

Comment: It has not been explained to satisfaction why this is any better than `git branch -f`. To be specific, this method appears to be: (A) harder to use (B) harder to remember, and (C) more dangerous

Comment: "what exactly is meant by arbitrary refs" - Branches are not the only kind of ref that points to a commit. There are tags, and you can also create arbitrary refs/whatevs/myref style refs yourself that are neither branches nor tags.

I believe that also answers Steven Lu's question about what this might be "better". I agree branch -f is simplest if you are working with branches.

Comment: refs from remotes is an example of how git uses refs that are not branches.  When you run `git fetch origin`, git will create refs inside `refs/remotes/origin/` that correspond to the branch heads from the `origin` remote.  `git-p4` will create refs in `refs/remotes/p4`, to emulate a remote called `p4`.  When recovering from a bad `git p4 sync`, using the `git update-ref` form allows you to move where the p4 branch head points to, to retry the sync.

Comment: "If you simply want to move a branch to another commit, ... This is how to move a branch pointer: ..." What is the distinction bring made here between a "branch" and a "branch pointer"? I thought a branch was basically just a pointer - albeit with certain behavior.

Comment: @Mot the documentation doesn't mention where the `-m` message goes, so I investigated, and updated the answer with my findings. `git update-ref -m "needle" refs/heads/master 889c5b5` followed by `grep -IRl "needle" .git` reveals the answer.

Comment: How do you update the origiin/ when you move the branch?  I can't delete the origin and upload the new branch. It's master branch!

Answer (score 1411):

```
git branch --force <branch-name> [<new-tip-commit>]
```

If `new-tip-commit` is omitted, it defaults to the current commit.

`new-tip-commit` can be a branch name (e.g., master, origin/master).

Comment: This is a better answer since it handles the 99% case and actually conforms to the documentation. `git help branch` says "       -f, --force
           Reset <branchname> to <startpoint> if <branchname> exists already.
           Without -f git branch refuses to change an existing branch."

Comment: Very useful if you want to change where another branch is pointing without checking it out.

Comment: This won't work if the branch you're trying to move is your current branch (`HEAD` points to it).

Comment: I wanted to move the head of my current branch back one commit: `git checkout HEAD^ && git branch -f mybranch HEAD && git checkout mybranch` worked for me.

Comment: What is 'new-tip-commit'?

Comment: This seems to have a side-effect. If your `new-tip-commit` is a remote branch, it is also set as the upstream for your `branch-name`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @starfry, the command for moving the head of your current branch is `git reset`. You'd do `git reset --hard HEAD^` or `git reset --keep HEAD^`, depending on the behavior you desire.

Comment: You may want to use `git checkout <branch-name>` after `git branch -f <branch-name>` otherwise you will end up with `head` still pointing at the `<new-tip-commit>`, that look confusing for me

Answer (score 162):

You can also pass `git reset --hard` a commit reference.

For example:

```
git checkout branch-name
git reset --hard new-tip-commit
```

I find I do something like this semi-frequently:

Assuming this history

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph
* 3daed46 (HEAD, master) New thing I shouldn't have committed to master
* a0d9687 This is the commit that I actually want to be master

# Backup my latest commit to a wip branch
$ git branch wip_doing_stuff

# Ditch that commit on this branch
$ git reset --hard HEAD^

# Now my changes are in a new branch
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph
* 3daed46 (wip_doing_stuff) New thing I shouldn't have committed to master
* a0d9687 (HEAD, master) This is the commit that I actually want to be master
```

Comment: This makes the most sense in that typically one uses HEAD or HEAD^ to move the branch tip back in time. So this is consistent to specify the  commit ahead.

Comment: This is fine if your working tree is clean. If you have lots of staged or unstaged changes, it's probably better to do `git update-ref` as discussed above.

Comment: Did you noticed that your “answer” does not add anything which is not part of the question already?? – OP said: if it is checked out... you can use `git reset --hard ...` No need to repeat it here! :-(

Comment: @Robert: I disagree. The question didn't say _how_ to use it and this does. It was nice not to have to go look for that how.

Comment: @WilsonF, maybe it was nice for you to find this here, but it is not answering the question at all. Maybe it is the answer of some other question, but here it is _wrong_.

Comment: my preferred method. There should totally be a `git repoint <commit>` command

Comment: I think this should maybe have been a comment on the question, not an answer. (Or maybe it was answering an earlier version of the question?)

Answer (score 72):

Just to enrich the discussion, if you want to move `myBranch` branch to your **current** commit, just omit the second argument after `-f`

Example:

`git branch -f myBranch`

---

I generally do this when I `rebase` while in a Detached HEAD state :)

Answer (score 23):

Git 2.23.0 introduced the [`git-switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command that can also be used to do this.

```
git switch -C <branch-name> [<start-point>]
```

The `-C` (uppercase C) option indicates that if `<branch-name>` already exists, it will reset it to `<start-point>`.

With `-c` (lowercase C) it will try to create a new branch but fails if one already exists.

`<start-point>` can be a hash, a tag, or another branch name.

Comment: I like this idea, but as of `git version 2.35.1` ... `git switch --help | egrep -i EXPERIMENTAL` said 
       `THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.`

Comment: The `git switch` command has been experimental from when it was introduced in version 2.23.0. See this from the Git Blog in August 2019 https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/

Comment: I'd say that it is normal for a new command to be introduced first as experimental. It simply means some of the options or flags might change, or others might be added or improved. The `-c|-C` flag behaviour discussed here has not changed since the command was introduced in August 2019.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to move a non-checked out branch to another commit, the easiest way is running the git branch command with -f option, which determines where the branch HEAD should be pointing to:

```
git branch -f <branch-name> (<sha1-commit-hash> or <branch-name>)
```

For example if you want your local develop branch to track the remote (origin) develop branch:

```
git branch -f develop origin/develop
```

Be careful as this won't work if the branch you are trying to move is your current branch.
To move a branch pointer, run the following command:

```
git update-ref -m "reset: Reset <branch-name> to <sha1-commit-hash>" \
  refs/heads/<branch-name> <sha1-commit-hash>`
```

The git update-ref command updates the object name stored in a ref safely.

Hope, my answer helped you.The source of information is [this snippet](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-move-branch-pointer-to-different-commit.html).

Answer (score 13):

In **`gitk --all`**:

- right click on the commit you want
- -> **create new branch**
- **enter the name of an existing branch**
- press return on the dialog that **confirms replacing the old branch of that name**.

Beware that re-creating instead of modifying the existing branch **will lose tracking-branch information**.  (This is generally not a problem for simple use-cases where there's only one remote and your local branch has the same name as the corresponding branch in the remote.  See comments for more details, thanks @mbdevpl for pointing out this downside.)

It would be cool if `gitk` had a feature where the dialog box had 3 options: overwrite, modify existing, or cancel.

---

Even if you're normally a command-line junkie like myself, `git gui` and `gitk` are quite nicely designed for the subset of git usage they allow.  I highly recommend using them for what they're good at (i.e. selectively staging hunks into/out of the index in git gui, and also just committing.  (ctrl-s to add a signed-off: line, ctrl-enter to commit.)

`gitk` is great for keeping track of a few branches while you sort out your changes into a nice patch series to submit upstream, or anything else where you need to keep track of what you're in the middle of with multiple branches.

I don't even have a graphical file browser open, but I love gitk/git gui.

Comment: So easy!  I may have just converted from gitg to gitk.

Comment: This way, however, the tracking branch information is lost.

Comment: @mbdevpl: I'm not really a git expert.  I think I understand what you mean, but not the implications.  I've used this fairly often, and still been able to push those branches to branches of the same name on a remote.  What does the association between a branch and its remote-tracking branch do for you?

Comment: @mbdevpl: does that mostly only matter [when your local branch has a different name from the remote branch it's tracking](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)?

Comment: @PeterCordes Ineed, when branch names don't match it matters. Also when there is more than one remote. Also when you're using git prompt to display branch status, it'll show commit distance to your tracking branch (if it's set). Also, `git status` output is affected. Additionally, in some cases `git fetch` and `git push` won't work without specifying remote explicitly if you don't set the tracking branch. I don't know about all the cases, but for me the general rule of thumb is that for convenience and speed of work, it's better to have tracking branches in order.

Comment: @PeterCordes As a side note, git sometimes sets tracking branch automatically. E.g. when you do `git checkout devel` but only `origin/devel` exists, git will automatically create and checkout `devel`, while also setting its tracking branch accordingly.

Comment: @mbdevpl: thanks, I added a warning to the answer about this drawback.  Feel free to make an edit yourself if you see room for improvement.

Answer (score 9):

The [recommended solution `git branch -f branch-pointer-to-move new-pointer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471174/git-move-branch-pointer-to-different-commit-without-checkout#answer-5471197) in [TortoiseGit](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tortoisegit/info):

- "Git Show log"
- Check "All Branches"
- On the line you want the branch pointer to move to (new-pointer):

  - Right click, "Create Branch at this version"
  - Beside "Branch", enter the name of the branch to move (branch-pointer-to-move)
  - Under "Base On", check that the new pointer is correct
  - Check "Force"
  - Ok

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Honestly, I'm surprised how nobody thought about the `git push` command:

```
git push -f . <destination>:<branch>
```

The dot ( . ) refers the local repository, and you may need the -f option because the destination could be *"behind its remote counterpart"*.

Although this command is used to save your changes in your server, the result is exactly the same as if moving the remote branch (`<branch>`) to the same commit as the local branch (`<destination>`)

Comment: You can also do this without `-f` to avoid clobbering anything local; for instance, `git fetch origin && git push . origin/develop:develop` is a no-checkout-needed fail-fast version of `git checkout develop && git pull --ff-only`

Answer (score 5):

Open the file `.git/refs/heads/<your_branch_name>`, and change the hash stored there to the one where you want to move the head of your branch. Just edit and save the file with any text editor. Just make sure that the branch to modify is not the current active one.

**Disclaimer:** Probably not an advisable way to do it, but gets the job done.

Comment: Not sure whether this is the chaotic or evil way to do it.  

Comment: @KeithRussell may be both :P

Comment: @KeithRussell, @G Merely chaotic, unless you're messing with a public repo! :-) In one sense, this is a supported way to do it, since the git documentation describes its inner workings in great detail. Being able to understand which files are updated how by, e.g. `git commit` is the most compelling reason to use git instead of mercurial.

Comment: @jpaugh, Question is how to ensure this operation is atomic?

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez, Is there a way to do this via the browser? (for github)

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think there is a way, these files are not accessible in the web repositories. The only way would be to do the change locally, and then `push --force` the branch. Be careful with that, though, as it will "overwrite" the remote branch with the local one.

Answer (score -4):

For the checked out branch, in the case the commit you want to point to is ahead of the current branch (which should be the case unless you want to undo the last commits of the current branch), you can simply do:

```
git merge --ff-only <commit>
```

This makes a softer alternative to `git reset --hard`, and will fail if you are not in the case described above.

To do the same thing for a non checked out branch, the equivalent would be:

```
git push . <commit>:<branch>
```

Comment: Question asked about what to do if the branch is not checked out.

Comment: Oops, I missed that point. In that case you could do `git push . <commit>:<branch>` as already suggested.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because a merge creates a new commit (and a new state of affairs). It doesn't simply update the branch pointer, unless you do a `git merge --ff-only`, and then only if there are no conflicts.

Comment: @jpaugh That's why I said in the case the commit you want to point to is ahead (I could also have precised and not behind). Yes you can use the `--ff-only` option if you want to be sure, but that option does not alter the way the merge is done, it just prevents non fast forward merges to be done. Also, if the merge is not fast forward, you can refuse the commit and cancel the merge with `git merge --abort`.

Comment: @JeanPaul You're clearly an expert with git, but many of your readers won't be. A novice needs to know not only which command to use, but in what context. Your last comment helps tremendously with that. But to answer the OP's question with `git merge` would require a few more commands to protect both the starting branch and the working tree. `git stash; git checkout <branch>; git merge --ff-only <commit>; git checkout <starting-branch>; git pop`