# What is the git command to fetch&merge non-fast-forward changes from an intermediate (bare) USB stick?

Tags: git

I use a USB stick with a bare git repo to propagate commits from a development PC to a server that is not immediately accessible.  One of my teammates committed some changes, and now I must merge.

I made some changes to my dev directory.  I committed them; I pushed them to the USB stick.  After I moved the USB stick to the computer with repo access the `git push` failed because it was not a fast forward on the origin.  A coworker had done some work and committed his changes and effectively there were now two branches.  I then performed a `git fetch` which pulled my coworker's commits from the origin onto the USB stick.

However, the USB stick with the bare repo still had its refs/heads/master pointing at the changes I had pushed from my dev box to the stick, while the refs/remote/origin/master was pointing at my coworker's changes that I had pulled from the origin onto the stick.

I was able to fetch the changes onto the USB stick, but now I do not know how to merge them onto the dev PC.  A plain `git merge` in my working directory tells me "Already up-to-date."  A plain `git merge` in my USB bare repo tells me "Fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree".

Inside the bare repository of the USB stick `git show-ref` tells me I have `refs/head/master` and `refs/remote/origin/master`, but I do not know the command to execute inside the development tree that will merge my tree with the remote/origin/master changes.

Comment: Just to double-check... do you have the local `master` branch checked out? What is the output of `git status`? Is your upstream still `origin/master`? What does `git remote get-url origin` say? Maybe your drive letter has changed for the USB stick and git can't find your remote?

Comment: Can you describe in more details the step : "I was able to fetch the changes onto the USB stick" ?

Comment: I have expanded the narrative to outline the steps I took to fetch the changes onto the USB stick.  As for JDB's questions:  The dev PC has master checked out.  The USB stick can't have things checked out because it is bare.  One upstream is `usbf/master`, and the other is `origin/master`.  The drive letters are fine.  `git remote -v` gives different answers from the dev PC and from the USB stick, naturally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch from the USB-stick repo into your server repo and merge the result.

```
git remote add USB /path/to/your/mountable/repo    # once
git fetch USB
git merge USB/master
```

edit: ah, okay, your origin/master changes weren't pushed or mirrored to your USB repo for some reason, you fetched them into a remote there.

```
git fetch USB +refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/*
```

will fetch `refs/remotes/origin/master` from your USB stick into `refs/remotes/origin/master` (and likewise with all the USB's remote refs) on yours.

edit: re the +refs/remotes/*: etc, that's a refspec, see the docs for fetch, push and fetch both use refspecs and explain them. It's a source:destination pattern with a leading + for allow-rewrites, Git fills in defaults intelligently enough that it's maybe even too easy to not know it's happening.  The default fetch refspec is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, neatly mapping the remote's branches to the local tracking refs.

Also see the docs for revisions, git tries the spelling you give it, then tries the `refs/`, then `refs/tags`, then `refs/heads`, then `refs/remotes` prefixes. SO `origin/master` usually finds `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

Comment: That does not actually solve the problem.  Because USB/master is not origin/master .  USB/master is my commits that will eventually become a branch on the main repo.

Comment: The added bit about the +refs/remotes/* is a syntax I had never seen before.  It appears to work.  I can not test the syntax for the subsequent merge since I already achieved my goal using a different technique, but I am optimistic it would be something like `git merge refs/remotes/origin/master` .

Answer (score 0):

It seems the root cause of the problem is that my USB stick (which I call usbf) has branch usbf/master which is *not* the same commit as origin/master.  When I pushed my changes to it the stick became sort of a branch relative to origin/master.  When I fetched changes from the origin, my USB stick now had two refs, one for each branch.

I was able to accomplish my mission using https://stackoverflow.com/a/45999240/995935 as a starting point.

In the USB stick's repo I did a

```
git branch -f master c0094ac0
```

so that now the master on the USB stick is the same as origin's master.  This also had the side-effect of turning my chain of commits on the USB stick into an unlabelled branch (I think?  Either way it is not a real problem, this is just the USB stick)

After that, I was able to hop into the dev directory and do a `git fetch` to retrieve the changes and a `git merge` to merge them.  After that a `git push` onto the USB stick; followed by a change of computers and a `git push` from the USB up to the main repo got me to the goal state.

If there is an alternate technique that does not require moving branches, I would be interested to learn it.