# how to find the git history of a remote branch after reset?

Tags: git, github

I have mistakenly reset the remote branch (not reverted).

```
  # git reset #hash
    # git push origin develop
```

I would like to check the latest commits made to that branch

How can i get all logs/history of that remote branch? (my local branch also uptodate with remote, so i couldn't see any changes there)

If I do;

```
# git log origin/develop
# git log develop
```

I could get logs upto reset point. Not after that.:(

Comment: If your local branch and the remote branch are the same, then `git log develop` and `git log origin/develop` are going to be identical.

Comment: @cmbuckley Yes, it shows only at that point where i reset. not the commits i made after. I would like to see those after from the rest point

Comment: What I mean is that your origin is not going to help in this scenario. Assuming you've made no more changes/commits to that branch, then `git log develop@{1}` is probably where you should start. See [<refname>@{<n>}](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-ltrefnamegtltngtegmaster1) in the git documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change a reference, which is what you do when you commit to a branch or reset it to a different commit, you can access prior values of that reference using the [`<refname>@{<n>}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-ltrefnamegtltngtegmaster1) format.

In your case, you should be able to see `git log develop@{1}` to see the log from the last tip of the develop branch.

The same is true for `origin/develop@{1}`, but "prior values" here won't necessarily include *all* changes, e.g. if a branch was committed to by someone else multiple times between your own `git fetch` commands.

In general, you can use `git reflog` to see changes to references, which will hopefully have a line like this near the top:

```
1234567 (HEAD -> develop) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 1234567abcde
```

Prior to that will be previous values of references of any branches you've checked out or committed to. You can use that to decide what to do next.

Comment: I have tried this # git reflog origin develop@{0} it gives //f47299b (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) develop@{0}: commit: updated common flows version
508db3f develop@{1}: reset: moving to 508db3f06254020828a622a5a518c08c1ecd2e81
a8f026d develop@{2}: commit: adding mock url
6c4e4e4 develop@{3}: pull: Fast-forward
8ac3ef2 develop@{4}: commit: adding dummy payload
5cf5346 develop@{5}: commit: adding dummy payload//

Comment: In the above i want to see waht happened i  this,//    6c4e4e4 develop@{3}: pull: Fast-forward  // How can i find code changes there?

Comment: Once you know a hash like that, you can just do something like `git show 6c4e4e4` or `git log -p 6c4e4e4` to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot..thats what i needed..great

Comment: `git log develop@{1}` was very useful for trouble-shooting after I used `git branch -f` to point a branch to a different commit. (Long story that involved the main branch of a repo in codecommit.) `git reflog` strikes me as un-intuitive -- I had no idea how to grok the results of that command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git reflog` command to find out at which commit (hash) the `develop` reference pointed before the reset, and use this hash as needed - create a new branch from it, reset develop back and restore pre-reset state, or just browse git log for that hash, depending on the needs. Then push the change again, to restore the state on the server as well.

Comment: it gives full log  git reflog origin develop@{0} . Now how should i see files changed at this commit?  //6c4e4e4 develop@{3}: pull: Fast-forward// I got it, git show 6c4e4e4 is the one i needed.Thanks