# Prepend a commit from master to a branch

Tags: git, branch

I started working on a new feature on master, by creating a commit `A`:

```
o -- A  (master)
```

before realizing that I should probably create a new branch. However, I didn't "move" the commit `A` to the new branch, so now my repo looks like this:

```
o -- A (master)
      \ 
       B - C - D - E (feature)
```

Luckily, I did not push to remote, nor are there any commits after `o` on master. How to move `A` from master to feature branch, and make my history look like this:

```
o (master)
 \
  A - B - C - D - E (feature)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: move branch pointer to different commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471174/git-move-branch-pointer-to-different-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a branch is just a pointer with new commits stacked on top of the original, you can do this:

First, make sure you are on master,

```
git checkout master
```

Then point master back at the origin by doing this (make sure you don't have any uncommitted changes as this will wipe them):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

And that should be it. You can check master with `git log` and then check your feature branch by doing

```
git checkout feature
git log
```