# Difference between `git branch -f <branch_name> <hash>` and `git checkout <branch_name>; git reset --hard <hash>` under a clean working tree?

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

Up until now, I have always used `git checkout <branch_name>; git reset --hard <hash>` to move a branch back to an earlier commit.

Then I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471174/git-move-branch-pointer-to-different-commit), but the answers and comments do not explain in great detail the differences between them.

Assuming I have a clean working tree, what internal differences are there between

```
git branch -f <branch_name> <hash>
```

and

```
git checkout <branch_name>
git reset --hard <hash>
```

and do such differences, if any, have any subtle implications for advanced usage?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The main difference is that `git branch -f <branchname> <commitref>` moves `<branchname>` to point the specified commit *without touching* `HEAD`, the *index* or the *working copy*, while `git checkout <branchname> && git reset --hard <commitref>` modifies all three.

If you want to quickly rearrange branches without moving `HEAD` or modifying your current working tree, then `git branch -f` is a good way to do it. It will also work if you have *uncommitted changes*, which isn't always possible if you use `git checkout`.

Another difference is related to performance, but it's only relevant for *very* large projects.
In those cases, modifying your working tree with `git checkout` and `git reset --hard` could potentially be an *expensive operation* with lots of disk I/O. On the other hand, with `git branch -f` only a *single file* will be written on disk, i.e. the one that contains the `<commithash>` referenced by `<branchname>`.

Comment: Good complete answer. I removed mine. +1