# How do you undo committing to a branch that's behind?

Tags: git

My coworker got himself into some trouble yesterday.  He moved `master` about 100 commits behind `origin/master` (I'm not sure how he did that, probably [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471197/61624)), then he committed.  The result was that `master` now was at his new commit and the previous commit was 100 commits behind `origin/master`.  It looked like this:

```
master * 
       |
       |  * origin/master 
       |  *
        ... ~one hundred commits below
       |  *
       \  *
         \
          *
```

I didn't feel confident in how to fix this so the way we did it is by throwing away the repo and cloning it again.  What's the right way to fix this mistake?

His *intent* was to create a new branch named `hotfix` 100 commits before `origin/master` and commit these changes to it.  I don't think he really wanted to move `master` at all.

---

I'll take a stab at fixing this:

```
git checkout master
git branch hotfix
#still on master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git branch -f master <commit of origin/master>
```

Comment: You just switch to `origin/master`, delete `master` and recreate it again. No need in explicit `reset`.

Comment: @zerkms what happens to that commit that master was on, assuming I didn't create hotfix yet.

Comment: It will be "unreachable" and collected by GC one day

Answer (score 1):

I'd just create a branch called `hotfix` and reset `master` to `origin/master`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch hotfix
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: That `reset` is intimidating.  I'll have to research how it works in that case.  Just for my info, would my attempt also work?

Comment: @DanielKaplan: I think so. You're doing a `reset` also, though.

Comment: Yeah that's fair, I am much more comfortable with a reset to HEAD~1 (which I do frequently) than a reset to a remote branch (which I've never done)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a git expert. This is the best I could come up with.

First, create a new branch with existing fixes:

```
git checkout -b oops <commit-id>
```

Then, switch back to master and remove the selected commit with:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto <commit-id>^ <commit-id>
```

Example: 
https://gist.github.com/cmattoon/13aa5c8d711a7ffc7899