# Is there some kind of 'git rebase --dry-run', which would notify me of conflicts in advance?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I'm trying to script rebasing and my script will take different paths depending on if the rebase results in any conflicts.

Is there a way to determine if a rebase would result in conflicts before executing the rebase?

Comment: What is the exact form of the `git rebase` command you're using? Are you using any optional flags? And what scripting language are you using? Shell?

Comment: If you run `git rebase` and hit a merge conflict, the process will stop and exit with a nonzero status. You could check the exit status of the rebase operation, and, if it is nonzero, run `git rebase --abort` to cancel the operation.

Comment: Did you find a way of doing this?

Comment: @crmpicco I basically did what Jubobs suggested by going ahead with the rebase, checking for conflict, and aborting if needed. I wish there was a more elegant way however...

Comment: For messy rebases, I often create a new branch and do a trial run there first.  If everything goes smoothly, the the trial run becomes the rebase, otherwise just switch back to the original branch.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

At the time of writing this (Git <del>v2.6.1</del> **v2.10.0**), the `git rebase` command offers no `--dry-run` option. There is no way of knowing, before actually attempting a rebase, whether or not you're going to run into conflicts.

However, if you run `git rebase` and hit a conflict, the process will stop and exit with a nonzero status. What you could do is check the exit status of the rebase operation, and, if it is nonzero, run `git rebase --abort` to cancel the rebase:

```bash
git rebase ... || git rebase --abort
```

And if the rebase is successful but you realise that you want to undo it, you can run

```bash
git reset --hard @{1}
```

Comment: @bluenote10 Or if you know that you will want to discard the rebase result no matter what, you can just start with a detached head: `git checkout --detach foo`.

Comment: You can also use `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` to move the branch back to where it was before the rebase.

Comment: Note that sometimes, `ORIG_HEAD`  will not point to where the branch tip was before the rebase. This can happen if you use ` git reset`  during the rebase, for example to split a commit (as of Git 2.39) ([see the bug report](https://lore.kernel.org/git/ef389a14-8513-4650-21e4-89421a24df2d@gmail.com/T/#t)). A safer alternative is ` git reset --hard @{1}`

Answer (score 52):

If you just want to see if the rebase *would be* successful but then you want to "roll back," **you can alway [reposition the branch tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471174/move-branch-pointer-to-different-commit-without-checkout) back to the original commit.** Just tag or make a note of the original SHA.

Or perhaps easier, create a new temporary branch in which to "stage" the rebase:

```
git checkout your-branch
git checkout -b tmp
git rebase other-branch
```

If it was successful but you want to "roll back," `your-branch` is untouched. Just `git branch -D tmp` and you're back to where you started from.

If there were conflicts and you did some work to resolve them and you now you want to keep the rebase, just reposition your-branch tip to `tmp` (and then `git branch -D tmp`).

Comment: A single command in place of the first two: `git checkout -b tmp your-branch`

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that `git rebase ... --dry-run` is not possible, for the following reason.

When you're doing a `git rebase`, git will rollback to the starting point, then incrementally apply patches for each commit to bring the branch up to date. If it hits a conflict, it will stop & wait for you to resolve the conflict before continuing. The path that the rebase takes after that conflict depends upon how you resolve the conflict - if you resolve it a certain way, that might introduce (or eliminate) later conflicts.

Thus, `git rebase ... --dry-run` would only be able to give you the **first** conflict - reports of later conflicts will depend upon how that first conflict is resolved.

The only way I can think of doing this would be via `git diff` between the current position and the last commit in the branch you're rebasing to. But that won't really give you what you're looking for - you really just need a list of **conflicting** changes between the two points. There *might* be a way to do it with `git diff`, but it's not a normal patch.

Answer (score 5):

You still can do git rebase, play with it as you want, than recover all the changes from before.
Assuming you have done your rebase of some branch into the `master`, and you don't like it:

1. `git reflog -20` - gives you last 20 positions of your HEAD with a little description
2. `git checkout <the_branch_name>` - places your HEAD on the branch
3. `git reset --hard <old_sha1_found_in_reflog>` - places your HEAD and branch on the old ref, this way you can recover old branch.

There are some mechanics to understand here:

1. You NEVER delete anything in git, not with commands, anyway. Its the garbage collector that comes through and deletes unreferenced branches (default 3 months). So your branch, from before the rebase, still exists.
2. Same goes for the on same branch rebase, its just a new tree rewritten next to the old one.
3. All the history of `rebase` and your other on HEAD manipulations is written in the `reflog`
4. You can use `@{N}` annotations from `reflog`

So, nothing is lost after the `rebase`, you just have to know how to find and recover it.

For example you can place yourself a tag before the `rebase` than revert to it or delete it. it evades you all the SHA1 research step.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [@joneit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48116816/968244)'s solution:

Create a new `temp` branch from `your-branch` and try to rebase that temp branch onto the `new-base`:

```
git checkout -b temp <your-branch> && git rebase <new-base>
```

e.g. to test if branch `feature1` can be rebase'd onto `master`:

```
git checkout -b temp feature1 && git rebase master
```

Answer (score -1):

```
git checkout ${BRANCH-HEAD}~0 && git rebase ...
```

But `--dry-run` was better

Comment: Is this a new answer (in which case how does it compare to the existing ones?), or is this just a warning/comment to use `--dry-run` before running the real command?

Comment: Do you mean "was better in the past, pity that it was removed" or "would be better"? Because the other answers seem to imply that there never was a dry-run. Also, please explain the first part, that looks like a code-only solution.