# git revert: Is it possible to identify potentially conflicting commits before actual revert?

Tags: git, git-revert

Is there a way to identify "collateral" commits (commits that are editing same lines and will result in a conflict) for the certain commit?

A very simplified example

```
$ git init
$ echo test > test
$ git add test
$ git commit -m "First commit"
$ echo test1 > test
$ git commit -am "Second commit"
$ git l
* 95a29dd Second commit
* 30a68e6 First commit
$ type test
test1
```

Assuming that at this point for whatever reason I want to revert `30a68e6`.

```
$ git revert 30a68e6
error: could not revert 30a68e6... First commit
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Naturally, this will result in a conflict, since `95a29dd`, edited the same line.

Is it possible to find out in advance that reverting `30a68e6` would result in a conflict, and if so, with what commit (i.e. `95a29dd`)?

To give a bit of context, I need this, because I need some commits to be reverted automatically. In this case, if I know that `30a68e6` should be reverted, I want to be able to identify "collateral" commits, that should be reverted first to avoid any conflict (like `30a68e6`). I know that just reverting everything `30a68e6..HEAD`, would work, but I would like to avoid reverting commits that will not conflict with `30a68e6`.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29517440/2541573

Comment: somewhat related: https://github.com/felipec/git-related

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: This answer is similar to my answer to [Is there some kind of 'git rebase --dry-run', which would notify me of conflicts in advance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29517440/2541573).)

> Is it possible to find out in advance that reverting `30a68e6` would result in a conflict, and if so, with what commit (i.e. `95a29dd`)?

At the time of writing (Git v2.7.0), Git provides no way of finding out, before actually attempting a revert, whether or not you're going to run into conflicts.

However, if you run `git revert` and hit a conflict, the process will stop and exit with a nonzero status. What you could do is check the exit status of the revert operation, and, if it is nonzero, run `git revert --abort` to cancel the revert:

`git revert ... || git revert --abort`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works partially, because it still doesn't allow me to find out which commit was causing the conflict. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`git revert` should be easy to undo. Check the return code of the revert, and run `git revert --abort` if it failed (return code 1) or `git reset --hard HEAD~1` if it succeded (return code 0) and you don't want to keep it.

You might be able to combine it with [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to search through the history, depending on your needs.

Comment: I know how to undo git revert, but that give me no information what commits were conflicting

Comment: I think the merging algorithm doesn't look at intervening commits, so you might have to find some way to manually test the intervening commits, either with bisect or with something else.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com /q/8435343/1463246. It's about `git log` for lines.