# git stash exits 0 but no stash created

Tags: git, git-pull, git-stash

I've been advised to [avoid `git pull --autostash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540878/5353461), and instead use:

```
git alias.pull-autostash '!git stash push && git pull --rebase && git stash pop'
```

When there are no changes in the index or working tree, doing:

```
$ git stash push
```

gives:

```
No local changes to save
```

An additional problem is that the exit status is `0`.

Any `stash pop` would then `pop` something which wasn't pushed.

How do I force an empty stash to be created, like `git commit --allow-empty`?

Answer (score 3):

For scripting, use `git stash create` (which produces the hash ID of the created stash on standard output, or nothing on standard output if no stash was created).  You can then use `git stash store` to insert the created stash as `stash@{0}`, if and only if one was actually created.

If your Git is too old to have `git stash create`, you can run two `git rev-parse` commands on `refs/stash` before and after running `git stash save`.<sup>1</sup>  These can:

- Both fail: there was no stash before and is no stash after.
- The first fails, the second succeeds: there was no stash before, and there is now, hence one was created.
- Both succeed, with the two output strings matching (no stash created) or differing (stash created).

Thus, if you use  `--quiet --verify` and capture the actual output from each, you can tell whether a stash was created.  That is, the programming fragment that applies here is:

```sh
old=$(git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/stash)
git stash save || die ...
new=$(git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/stash)
if [ "$old" != "$new" ]; then
    made_stash=true
else
    made_stash=false
fi
... do things ...
if $made_stash; then ... do things with the stash you made ...
```

(I recommend avoiding both `git stash` *and* `git pull` except in very limited, specialized circumstances.  I've had too many bad experiences with them.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If your Git lacks `git stash create`, it probably predates `git stash push` as well and hence you need `git stash save` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not answer how you stash an empty change but it should solve your problem.

Check if there are pending changes first (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879077/3526980)

```sh
$ git alias.pull-autostash '(git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- && git pull --rebase) || (git stash push && git pull --rebase && git stash pop)'
```

Comment: You need `git diff-files` as well: diff-index compares the index but does not look at the work-tree, while `git stash` creates a stash (two commits, one for the index and one for the work-tree) if either the index *or* the work-tree are dirty.

Comment: @Torek why not `[ -z "$(git status -uno --porcelain)" ] && echo clean`?

Comment: @TomHale: That probably will suffice, since you don't care which is dirty (index, work-tree, or both), just whether at least one is.