# Why avoid `git pull` and what to do instead

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, pull, git-fetch

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538050/exit-status-is-0-but-autostash-requires-manual-merging#comment92077148_52540878), 
[@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) (reputation currently 172,509) said:

> I actually recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely, for the same reason you recommend avoiding `--autostash`

The [reason given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540878/5353461) for avoiding `git rebase --autostash` was:

> It seems convenient when it works but is problematic when it doesn't

In which ways can `git pull` be problematic when it doesn't work?

[My robust automated solution to avoiding `git pull --autostash` is non-trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52870006/5353461).

Is there a robust automated solution to avoiding `git pull`?

Comment: What does `pull` have to do with `rebase --autostash`? Also, remember a pull is just a fetch then a merge.

Comment: @evolutionxbox presumably it's a series of commands (stash push, rebase, stash pop / fetch merge) which can lose information (eg exit status). See the links for more context.

Comment: "Robust" tends to be hard. Since pull = fetch + 2nd-git-command, run `git fetch` (which is pretty safe at all times assuming standard configurations), then build the robust part around whichever second command you want.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://adamcod.es/2014/12/10/git-pull-correct-workflow.html

Comment: @chevybow Excellent, that was the answer I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Don’t avoid pull: create lots of branches, and communicate when merging.

Comment: [This old guide](https://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) explains the point rather well IMO:

Answer (score 1):

No need for avoiding git pull: [since Git 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), type:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

Then a simple `git pull` will do, in essence, what your [better workflow](https://adamcod.es/2014/12/10/git-pull-correct-workflow.html) is about: rebase if needed your current branch on top of the fetched `origin/yourBranch`.

Comment: One reason to avoid doing this is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52538050/5353461), namely a `0` exit status even though the stash failed to reapply.