# How to know in C# process response if git rebase resulted conflict or successful

Tags: c#, git, rebase, startprocessinfo

I am running git commands using `Process` from `cmd.exe`, everything works fine, now I am trying to rebase a branch and want to know if rebase got successful then want to run the `git push` command as next step.

Is there any way to know if git rebase got successful without conflict from the response message of `Process`?

Because when it got successful it gives this response `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/qa.`

I checked this question
[Is there some kind of 'git rebase --dry-run', which would notify me of conflicts in advance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29517440/is-there-some-kind-of-git-rebase-dry-run-which-would-notify-me-of-conflicts)

The answer says if it is a non-zero response that means it is not successful but rebase does not give response in that 0/1 format, it returns text.

My code is this

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c git rebase master");
procStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

proc.WaitForExit();

// What should I check here to make sure rebase happened without conflicts
var response = await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```

Comment: A command's numeric return value is separate from its output, so I think this question boils down to "how do I get a process's return value in C#".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check Process.ExitCode property. In most case if there some error, code will be non-zero. I think git isn't a exception.