# Get previous project version

Tags: git

My `git log` was showing several project commits in my projects. I'm using only master branch. I have done git checkout to first commit. I was expecting that my directory will be changed to state when it was in during first commit. It not happened. How to achieve that?

Now git console shows that I'm in first commit by showing `((b266cf..))` instead of `(master)` in command prompt. And `git log` shows that there is only one commit - first one? Where others are gone? How to get back to state where all others commits are visible?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  You checked out some commit in the detached HEAD state, which may not be what you wanted to do.  If you can clue us in about your desired goal maybe someone can help you.

Comment: how to get out from detached HEAD state? And I would like "git log"  show all logs - not only first on like it is currently

Comment: Just checkout the branch again, i.e. `git checkout master` ... but what were you trying to do?

Comment: "git checkout master" brings back (master) in command prompt, "but git log" still shows only first commit. Where are others?

Comment: I don't know where the other commits are, but what you are seeing in `master` is what is actually there.  Perhaps you can try doing `git pull origin master` to get any new commits coming from the repository?

Answer (score 0):

> `git log` shows that there is only one commit - first one?

That is expected: if you checkout the first commit, `git log` will show all commits accessible since that checked out commit. Since it is the first one, `git log` only shows this one.

> "`git checkout master`" brings back `(master)` in command prompt, but "`git log`" still shows only first commit. Where are others?

If somehow master is not properly restored, check the output of [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Any commit you have done in that repo is listed in `git reflog`: you will be able to [reset `master` to the commit you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8206536/6309).

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <another_commit_sha1>
```

Or `git branch -f master new-tip-commit` (might not work if `master` is the currently checked out branch)