# GIT - Replace a branch content with another

Tags: git

I have the following branches in my local git:

```
-master
-develop
-test
```

I am adding a new feature, using the test branch, which was created months ago. I need to update its content (replace everything) with the develop branch.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to effectively discard the current `test` branch and create it new with the same state as `develop`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 exactly

Comment: Try with `git pull origin develop` from you test branch

Comment: @mkrieger1 it is already created with no up-to-date content. I want to replace its state with the develop state.

Comment: @Dineshkarthik I think this is not a full replace, but just add new modification from develop branch.

Comment: @RAZAFINARIVOHanania yeah but if `develop` is ahead of `test` i think it will replace whole branch?

Comment: So just one of `git checkout test; git reset --hard develop` or `git checkout -B test develop` or any of the solutions shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471174/move-branch-pointer-to-different-commit-without-checkout)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 aw sorry I just read your last comment after answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one go, recreate `test` branch from where `dev` is, and check it out :

```
git checkout -B test develop
```

[(doc for the `-B` option)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--Bltnewbranchgt)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `develop` branch

```
git checkout develop
```

Remove the `test` branch

```
git branch -d test
```

Create a new branch called `test`

```
git checkout -b test
```

The new branch `test` will contain all content of develop branch.